# How do I get the dot products of corresponding rows in two arrays?

Tags: python, numpy

How do I perform this without using for loops and just numpy functions?

```py
import numpy as np
arr_x = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
arr_y = np.array([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])

res = []
for x, y in zip(arr_x, arr_y):
    res.append(np.dot(x, y))
np.array(res)  # array([14, 77])
```

I tried `tensordot` with axes=1, but that throws a shape mismatch error.

Comment: Can you plz post your desired output?

Comment: `np.einsum("ij,ij->i", arr_x, arr_y)`

Comment: As per the suggested duplicate, both `np.einsum('ij,ij->i', arr_x, arr_y)` and `np.sum(arr_x*arr_y,axis=1)` should get you to `array([14, 77])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the @hmn Falahi answer, which works fine, you can consider to use a more intuitive approach: a dot product of two arrays is simply the sum of the products of each pair of the two vectors. Basing on this definition you can simply obtain `res` with:

```
res = (arr_x * arr_y).sum(axis=1)
```

I attach this other solution that I like, but that is probably memory inefficient for your purpose:

```
res = np.diag(arr_x @ arr_y.T)
```

This is also very intuitive and is based on taking the diagonal of the matrix multiplication of the two matrices you have.

Answer (score 1):

Try `(arr_x*arr_y).sum(1)`

Explanation:
`(arr_x*arr_y)` multiplies each vector elements and the `sum(1)` calculate the sum of element production as in the dot product.